# Sign In With Google: refresh token in background

Tags: javascript, google-signin

How Do I refresh auth token when using Sign In With Google?

With "Sign In With Google" it seems the user has to confirm being logged in every 30 minutes. Unfortunately, this often happens why interacting with the website. This frustrates users and cause recent changes not to be saved.

This wasn't a problem with the old library where it was possible to refresh the token in background. How to do token refresh with the new library?

It seems there is no API for that:

[Sign In With Google JavaScript API reference](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/reference/js-reference)  .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the new "Sign in with Google" system, Google only handles the original authentication. It is not intended to manage a user session and you are required to do that yourself/in some other way.

Comment: I am confused here. What are you supposed to do when the JWT google gives you for a successful sign in expires. Its exp is set to last for only one hour? What is the other way you are supposed to handle this?

Comment: @bhspencer you need to have a separate system for Authorization. after signing in in the first place, you need a different solution to keep a user signed in, such as your own JWTs

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled [Automatic sign-in](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/automatic-sign-in-sign-out#sign-in-users-automatically)

```
<div id="g_id_onload"
     data-client_id="YOUR_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID"
     data-auto_select="true"
     data-login_uri="https://your.domain/your_login_endpoint">
</div>
```

Comment: Automatic sign in does not work in any scenario in which the user is has multiple google accounts, and therefor is not a suitable way to resolve this problem.